# JQuery Mobile Event Debugger Use

Tags: php, session, jquery-mobile

here is my first question after a few years of finding great answers here at stack overflow.

I am desperately trying to put together a fairly simple login access only page using JQuery Mobile.  I'm getting stuck trying to get certain JQuery scripts to work.

I would like to have my php script start a SESSION.  I think I'm running into an issue with the script running twice (known issue (by design) with JQM) and starting two different SESSIONS.

I think I could solve the issue if I could figure out how to use the [JQuery-Mobile-Event-Debugger](https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-event-debugger) tool.  I think if someone could just give me an example of where to put the jquery.mobile.event.debugger.js bit and the $.mobile.eventlogger([showAlert]); bit (assuming that's how to get the options to work), I would be able to be off and running.

I'm using JQM version 1.4.3, JQuery 1.8.3 and PHP 5.3.  Please assume that the php page I'm trying to run the debugger on includes JQuery Mobile and JQuery files, some other validation javascript files (please see the sample of my main php page code below (it has a side panel that brings into view a login page that uses JQuery's AJAX functionality to compare the credentials to my MySQL database which successfully confirms that the credentials are correct and then the login page in the sidebar tries to start the SESSION)) I'm also trying to use a modified [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) method to initiate SESSIONS.

```
<?php

//=============Configuring Server and Database=======
include_once '***/***/function.php';

sec_session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Libraries/gmaps.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Libraries/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Libraries/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Libraries/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Libraries/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Libraries/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="***/formvalidate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="***/mobijav.js"></script>
        <style>
            .full-width-slider input {
                display: none;
            }
            .full-width-slider .ui-slider-track {
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
        </style>
     </head>
```

I hope this gives enough information for what I'm trying to do.  Please help.

Comment: you want to debug _pageContainer_ events?

Comment: I'm expecting jquery-mobile-event-debugger to alert me at the start of each event as per the events listed [here](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)

Comment: Bump - I'm just looking for help on how to make the jquery-mobile-event-debugger work, surely someone knows how to do that.

Comment: I tried using that library but I got an error. Anyway, you don't a library to know which event is fired. Use this simple fiddle to listen to pageContainer events http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u7XEq/ I'll write a new article explaining how to use them properly.

Comment: Thank you Omar, I should have looked into your blog more.  I would plus 1 your comment if I could.